# Como abrir SearchView na ActionBar programaticamente?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Vamos lá gente, a dúvida é a seguinte: Estou querendo abrir o SearchView a partir de um click em um item no Drawer (aquele menu lateral). Até agora tenho visto vários tutoriais sobre, porém só encontro como abrir o SearchView clicando no icone do SerachView(a forma padrão de abrir). Se alguém conhecer algum tutorial ou souber como fazer, por favor, me expliquem. Abraços!

Comment: Já chegou a fazer alguma dessas soluções? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122448/always-expanded-searchview-not-in-the-action-bar/24123185#24123185?

Answer (score 1):

Em seu OnClickListener, use:

```
myMenu.expandActionView() // ou collapseActionView();
```

Não se esqueça de adicionar as ações do menu:

```
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
```